# Improve SD logger - 0.02% of data isn't logged at desired rate

Tags: esp32, sd

I'm working on a project to read data over CAN, display it on LCD and log data to SD card. LCD is on HSPI and SD card on VSPI. CAN and LCD code is working on core 1 and SD on core 0, there's no wifi. It's all working pretty well but now I'm looking for further improvements. I set the log to 20 Hz and took a sample of 117024 lines. Below is the "uniq -c" output of the seconds that weren't logged at 20 Hz (left column is the actual rate and right column is a specific second in the log). So only 21 out of 117024 lines. But why does this happen and how can I make sure that every line is logged at 20 Hz?

```
     18 3195
     17 5393
     16 5401
     16 1622
     14 5397
     14 1628
     14 1625
     14 1624
     13 5400
     13 5398
     13 5396
     13 5395
     13 5394
     13 1626
     12 1631
     12 1630
     12 1627
     12 1623
      8 5399
      8 1629
```

```cpp
float timeStamp;
char filenameBuffer[23];
String filename;
bool logStarted = 0;
uint32_t lastSyncTime = 0, logStartTime = 0;

File file;

void initSD()
{
    if (SD.begin(5, SPI, 80000000))
    {
        Serial.println("Card Mount OK");
        updateFromFS(SD);
        generateFileName();
        sdInitialised = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
        return;
    }
}

void logToSD()
{
    if (!sdInitialised) return;
    if (!EMUfresh) return;

    if (!logStarted)
    {
        file = SD.open(filenameBuffer, FILE_APPEND);
        if (file)
        {
            file.print("Time,RPM,MAP,TPS,IAT,CLT,Lambda,PulseWidth,EGT1,EGT2,Vbatt,Baro,IgnAngle,LambdaCorr,Gear,Pwm1,Vss,EmuTemp,CEL,FLAGS1,LambdaTarget,OilTemp,OilPress,CanState\r\n");
            logStartTime = millis();
            logStarted = true;
        }
    }
    
    uint32_t duration = millis() - logStartTime;
    uint32_t seconds = duration / 1000;
    uint32_t milliseconds = duration % 1000;
    String dataString = "";
    
    dataString += seconds;
    dataString += ".";
    if (milliseconds < 100) { dataString += "0"; }
    if (milliseconds < 10) { dataString += "0"; }
    dataString += milliseconds;
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.RPM);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.MAP);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.TPS);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.IAT);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.CLT);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.lambda);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.pulseWidth);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.EGT1);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.EGT2);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.vBat);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.baro);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.ignAngle, 0);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.lambdaCorr, 0);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.gear);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.pwm1);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.vssSpeed);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.emuTemp);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.cel);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.flags1);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.lambdaTarget);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.oilTemperature);
    dataString += ",";
    dataString += String(emu_data.oilPressure);
    //dataString += ",";
    //dataString += String(can_error_data.state[1]); //Only first character
    dataString += "\r\n";

    file.print(dataString.c_str());

    if (millis() - lastSyncTime > 1000)
    {
        lastSyncTime = millis();
        file.flush();
    }
}

void generateFileName()
{
    char intBuffer[5];
    
    strcpy(filenameBuffer, "/");
    itoa(random(1000, 9999), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, "-");
    itoa(random(10), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, "-");
    itoa(random(10), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, "_");
    itoa(random(10), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, ".");
    itoa(random(10), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, ".");
    itoa(random(10), intBuffer, 10);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, intBuffer);
    strcat(filenameBuffer, ".csv");
    
    Serial.println(filenameBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Excess usage of String class is bad. Use a fixed char buffer instead

Comment: Can you also show the code that calls the function logToSD() at 20Hz ?
In the meantime,  maybe read this to see if it applies: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-millis.html heading "Arduino millis not accurate". 
In principle,  constructs like this (which you've used elsewhere) 
`if (millis() - lastSyncTime > 1000) { lastSyncTime = millis(); //...; }` should be written as 
`if (millis() - lastSyncTime > 1000) { lastSyncTime +=1000; //...; }` due to the way millis() derives 1000 milliseconds from 1024 timer ticks.

Comment: See also this thread for a discussion about the behaviour of millis() when timing regular events: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/millis-not-in-sync-with-8mhz-system-clock/179267