# FastLED web client, clicked on page to control on and off for ws2812

Tags: rgb-led, ws2812

FastLED web client, when clicked on, all RGB on in red color. Clicked off, all RGB off/black. but not work.
Here is the full code, i don't know why it's loop always and web client stuck when i clicked on button on webpage

I can not turn on all LED, or turn off all LED.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <FastLED.h>
#define DATA_PIN 5
#define NUM_LEDS 300
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
#define BRIGHTNESS 254
#define FRAMES_PER_SECOND 30


// Enter your wifi network name and Wifi Password
const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// These variables store current output state of LED
String outputRedState = "off";


// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int redLED = 5;





// Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis();
// Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
// Define timeout time in milliseconds (example: 2000ms = 2s)
const long timeoutTime = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);


  //FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  LEDS.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);  // 初始化光带
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);                     // 设置光带亮度
  set_max_power_in_volts_and_milliamps(5, 2000);         // 光带电源管理（设置光带5伏特，500mA）


  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();  // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                     // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("New Client.");  // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";        // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) {  // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();
      if (client.available()) {  // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();  // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);         // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {  // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();

            // turns the GPIOs on and off
            if (header.indexOf("GET /2/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("RED LED is on");
              outputRedState = "on";

              fill_solid(leds, 300, CRGB::Red);
              FastLED.show();



            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /2/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("RED LED is off");
              outputRedState = "off";

              fill_solid(leds, 300, 0);
              FastLED.show();
            }

            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // CSS to style the on/off buttons
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
            client.println(".buttonRed { background-color: #ff0000; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px; border-radius: 60%;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".buttonOff { background-color: #77878A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px; border-radius: 70%;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}</style></head>");

            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("<body><h1>My LED Control Server</h1>");

            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for GPIO 2 Red LED
            client.println("<p>Red LED is " + outputRedState + "</p>");
            // If the outputRedState is off, it displays the OFF button
            if (outputRedState == "off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/2/on\"><button class=\"button buttonOff\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/2/off\"><button class=\"button buttonRed\">ON</button></a></p>");
            }

            client.println("</body></html>");

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else {  // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Comment: `but not work` ... what does this mean?

Comment: `all RGB on in red color` ... what color are the supposed to be?

Comment: please clean up your code ... it is not indented properly, which makes errors very difficult to identify ... do yourself a favor, and spare yourself a world of hurt by learning how to format your code properly

Comment: look at the code at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/91113/improve-sd-logger-0-02-of-data-isnt-logged-at-desired-rate .... that is what properly formatted code looks like

Comment: What i want to do is, access web link, http://x.x.x.x/2/on, LED strip of 300 NUM_LED on, and then if click button off, all LED strip off.

But i encounter device stuck when i clicked on, sometime LED not all switch on, and the web seems no response, then wait few seconds, try to click on again, sometime the LED can all on. But off LED totally not work.

Comment: people will not spend time looking at your code when it is presented unformatted ... it should be easy to read here, on this page ... people should not have to copy your code and paste it into an editor, format it and then read it

Comment: this may help ... https://www.martyncurrey.com/esp8266-and-the-arduino-ide-part-6-javascript-and-ajax .... look at the last sketch at `AJAX With Acknowledgement`   ................... here is another https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/web-server-read-switch-using-AJAX/

Comment: just re-format. thanks. Sorry about my mistake

Comment: My expectation is all 300 Leds turn-on when i clicked button, but sometimes, only Led[0] on,  then i need to refresh "x.x.x.x/2/on" few times, then finally all Led on.